# Is there an alternative way to load an LDIF besides ldapadd/ldapmodify?

Tags: database, import, ldap, openldap, ldif

I get an error when using `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify`. The `ldapsearch` is also not working right now. I think it's an issue with BDB indexing.

```
$ ldapadd -Wx -D "cn=Manager,o=DIR" -f SC_TRANSPORT.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: *****
adding new entry "cn=SC_TRANSPORT,ou=Groups,ou=Source,o=DIR" 
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80) 
additional info: internal error
```

Comment: What is the reason for not using `ldapadd` or `ldapmodify`?

Comment: When I am using ldapmodify or ldapadd it shows some error,So is there any alternate .It seems to be some issue with indexing

Comment: Hi Terry,Thanks a lot for your inputs. The following is the error that we get when using ldapadd or ldapmodify. Important to note here is ldapsearch is not able to retrieve data from the branch, but still we are unabl eto add/modify the dn. I guess there is some issue with the openldap indexing and DB. Your inputs will be very valuable to resolve my problem.

Comment: ./ldapadd -h hostname -D cn=Manager,o=DIR -x -W -f SC_TRANSPORT.ldif                                           
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "cn=SC_TRANSPORT,ou=Groups,ou=Source,o=DIR"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: internal error

Comment: Has the `o=dir` entry been created in the backend?

Comment: Hi Terry,Hope the error gives you some hint as to what the issue could be and how to resolve it.

Comment: Yes it was created explicitly. The search fails only for some enties like the one mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Apache Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) and use it to connect and then use Apache Studio to import an LDIF file.

-jim

Answer (score 0):

You may use JNDI to do the same but that will not be faster than using ldif. But provides you an option where you can handle the failures explicitly.